# What is the maximum amount of data i passed through querystring of jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery

What is the maximum amount of data i passed through querystring of jquery ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Query strings form part of the URL for an HTTP GET request, so the main limit you'll hit is URL length.

Here's a question about that:
[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

So for typical browsers stay inside of 2,000 characters in total. But keep in mind that other clients may not deal with URLs of this length (e.g. proxy / caching servers).

I'd recommend that staying under 500 characters you should be safe. Anything more and consider using a POST request instead.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on the browser and/or server

IE 4.0 and above is ~2048 characters

All other browsers seem to support much more.  So basically if you are trying to implement a cross browser web site/application then its probably best not to exceed 2048 characters.

Also note Web servers can be configured to limit the amount of data passed though a QueryString.  This is rare but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum url length for any http request varies from browser to browser.  Jquery won't limit you, but the browser the request is being made from will.

See this post:
[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)